# Why did the Fallen Star wake the undead?

Tags: diablo-iii

The Fallen Star in Act I is not in and of itself demonic, so why did it crashing into the Tristram Cathedral cause minions of hell to burst forth?  Was it intentionally directed to impact there?

If it simply broke some seals containing all this badness, the odds for it to hit just so seem astronomically small; did some demonic influence guide it like a [JDAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Direct_Attack_Munition) from Heaven (but controlled by Hell)?  (I'm part-way through Act II; so I know what the star's made of; is more revealed about the impact going forward?)

Comment: I am not into act 2 yet, but Cain did state that the falling star was simply a sign of the end times, not the necessarily the cause of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Stranger has a line about it in A Royal Audience (Act II).

His explanation is a spoiler:

> Since Tyrael is the archangel of justice, his essence was leaking out and awakening all the dead who were *unjustly* killed.

> Also, apparently, this is something that he has to wrestle with constantly, and takes concentration to keep from happening even when he has control.

Comment: You can actually use the >! spoiler tag if you want :)

Comment: Oh cool!  They eat my paragraphs though, and all the sentences run together :(

Comment: Herm, breaking it apart with explicit &nbsp;'s seems to do the trick, somewhat

Comment: That is very very odd...

Comment: I always thought it was a cool touch to see mini impact sites and all the blue effect where the fragments of the sword fell as well.

Answer (score 0):

From the book of cain, the dead can be awaken by either demon's or angel's activity.

So, it doesn't matter whom or what is the falling star. To awaken the dead it suffices that the falling star has either demonic or angelic "energy".

> Tyrael is the falling star and he never ceases to be an angel.

Comment: he does cease to be an angel he forfeited his angelic status once he left haven thus making him mortal well from what i understood when i played

Comment: This is not true, there is plenty of evidence. One of the game dialogues, from the enchantress Eirena to the player: "Well, I did not expect you to keep company with a seraph." Seraph is the collective name for archangels and angels.

Comment: This could also be argued because how would Eirna know the current status of his angel status? She could possibly known that he was an angel but not know the current status.

Comment: Perhaps, but here is another prove. In the book of Cain says that demonic or angelic activity can awaken the dead. Now, we know that after the falling star smashes the Tristram cathedral, the dead awaken; Tyrael is not a demon. Thus, he is an angel.

Comment: maybe its like kratos in god of war even though he lost his god status he still retained some of his power for reasons i don't remember (not even sure they tell you). That could be the same reson why Tyrael still is the cause of the undead waking. if you know what i mean that is

Comment: For the purpose of this question, all we care about is that he has angelic essence. For further discussion onto whether he is an angel or not we can go on here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69717/what-is-tyrael